# how to move process from one namespace to other?

Tags: linux, process, lxc, namespaces

Is there any available method to move process/group of processes from one namespace to other in Linux? I mean methods via commands of some packages or it can be done via `setns()`? E.g. I have processes of current session in one namespace and some other processes of lxc container in different namespace, so I want to run (e.g. links) in cgroup of that container (it's easily do with cgexec) and then move it to container's namespace , because I have to run this process in container without executing it exact in it. Can it be done or it's impossible in Linux?